# hosts on school lab network go unreachable by ping, but are accessing the internet

Tags: networking, ssh

I've got a weird scenario in my high school lab:

- computers are connected to wifi and the internet
- kids are on websites, playing games, streaming audio, active internet connection

However, when I log into a computer I use to push updates and manage remotely, I'm unable to ping + ssh to many of the hosts which are currently active.

I'm using host.local addressing space, so say I login to `lab07.local` and then try to `ssh lab22.local` and can't resolve the hostname. This can last a few seconds or even a couple minutes and then connectivity comes back at some point.

Could this have something to do with the way .local addresses are resolved? should I try some sort of naming convention? Maybe I'll try with IP's directly this next time.

Comment: Are these computers all running Ubuntu? Are they all running ssh servers? Is `.local` provided by an MDNS service such as Avahi? Or are you trying to replace it with actual DNS entries?

Comment: all Ubuntu yes, ssh servers yes. As far as `.local` I need to study up. I thought this was a function of broadcasting on the same subnet. Gives me something to go on, thanks.

Comment: No, the `.local` domain is reserved for MDNS, which I do not think OpenSSH does by default (and I'm not sure if it supports it at all).

Comment: well for what it's worth, when the network is quiet I get excellent connectivity. During the day with students all around it's more choppy. So it is definitely working *some* of them time, and looks like traffic on the network can affect things.